# Variable confusion in a For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, scope, variable-assignment

In the example below, it is as if Python does not discriminate between `angle[u][v]` and `radius[u][v]`.

That is, from the first command in the for loop, an element of the `angle` array is evaluated. Then, from the second command in the for loop, the corresponding element of the `radius` array is evaluated.  My problem is that this value for `radius[v][u]` gets then overwritten onto `angle[v][u]`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import math

X = np.arange(0, 656, 1)
Y = np.arange(0, 667, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
X = X - 243 + 0.0
Y = Y - 363 + 0.0

angle = X
radius = X

height = X.shape[0]
width = X.shape[1]

print width
print height

for v in xrange(height):
    for u in xrange(width):
        angle[v][u] = math.atan2(X[v][u],Y[v][u])
        radius[v][u] = math.sqrt(X[v][u]**2 + Y[v][u]**2)
print angle
print radius
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Canonical duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd say is related, but here the OP has not yet realized he wants to copy the object :)

Comment: @mescalinum the duplicate explains both the problem and the solution. Did you imagine this had *never* been covered?

Comment: then a better duplicate of this should exist

Comment: @mescalinum *"better"* how? Note that you can edit it if you think you can improve it, which is more useful than answering the same question yet again.

Answer (score 0):

```
angle = X
radius = X
```

`angle` and `radius` are references to the same object `X`.
When you change one, you are changing `X`, and vice versa.

Have a look at this example, with `X` and `Y`:

```
>>> X = np.arange(0,2)
>>> Y = X
>>> X, Y
(array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))
>>> X[0] = 5
>>> X, Y
(array([5, 1]), array([5, 1]))
```

You should `copy` X if you don't want this behavior.

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> X = np.arange(0,2)
>>> Y = copy(X)
>>> X, Y
(array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))
>>> X[0] = 5
>>> X, Y
(array([5, 1]), array([0, 1]))
```